# Reordered output despite critical section

Tags: c, openmp

I'm trying to adapt this pascal triangle program to a parallel program using OpenMp.  I used the `for` directive to parallelize the `printPas` function for loop, and put the conditional statements inside of the critical section so only one thread can print at a time, but it seems like I'm still getting a data race because my output is really inconsistent.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef N
#define N 2
#endif
unsigned int t1[2*N+1], t2[2*N+1];
unsigned int *e=t1, *r=t2;
int l = 0;

//the problem is here in this function
void printPas() {
  #pragma omp parallel for private(l)
  for (l=0; l<2*N+1; l++) {
    #pragma omp critical
    if (e[l]==0)
      printf("      ");
    else
      printf("%6u", e[l]);
  }
  printf("\n");

}

void update() {
  r[0] = e[1];
#pragma omp parallel for
  for (int u=1; u<2*N; u++)
    r[u] = e[u-1]+e[u+1];
  r[2*N] = e[2*N-1];
  unsigned int *tmp = e; e=r; r=tmp; 
}

int main() {
  e[N] = 1;
  for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    printPas();
    update();
  }
  printPas();
}
```

Comment: Compute in parallel, output sequentially.

Comment: This is **not** a data race, it is simply reordered output.

Comment: Thank you everyone, this makes much more sense now

Comment: There is a `#pragma omp ordered` clause that force the following statement block within an `omp for` loop to be executed in sequence. This is even stronger than the `omp critical` clause, costs at least as much overhead and is more likely to cause threads to pause (since they can enter the block not only if noone else is there, but if all threads for preceding iterations have already gone through). It is obviously worth parallelizing the code with such clause only if there are significant calculations to do outside the serialized `ordered` block.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your critical section is causing the prints to run sequentially. Therefore, the code takes longer using 'critical' than it would if you didn't attempt to parallelise it.

Using different threads to print, you have no idea which one will access the critical section first. Therefore, the for-loop will not execute in the order that you would hope.

I suggest either removing the parallel directive ("#pragma omp parallel for private(l)"), or removing the 'critical' and accepting that the prints will come out in a different order every time.